# Make 1 div screen centered + 1 div at the right

Tags: html, css

pretty sure it has been answered somewhere but I couldn't find anything.

I'm trying to set up the blog post page and would like the content to be screen-centered with the sidebar to stick to the right. like below. Thanks for your help.

[image of the layout I try to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UX7Ye.png)

Comment: you can use grid. possible example  `.main {display:grid;grid-template-columns:1fr auto 1fr;} .div1{grid-column:2;width:xx;}.div2{grid-column:3;}` You should post your minimal code to reproduce your issue. poor question are closed. Welcome

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.main-div{
  width: 100%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1px;

}
.div-1{
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
.div-2{
  position: fixed;
  right:10px;
  top:30px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  main-div
  <div class="div-1">div-1</div>
  <div class="div-2">div-2</div>
</div>
```